# sorting and filtering options in WPF Datagrid?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, filtering

I installed the most recent WPF toolkit and used the Datagrid control.
The list of items is showing with automatically-generated columns based on my IList as ItemsSource.

I was wondering if there is an OOTB way to have filtering/sorting on this grid?
A way to click the header to make it sort, or use a dropdown in the header that shows all the possible values so that column is filtered on that property.

Right now my grid is just a fancy list of items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable filtering, sorting and grouping, you can use the ICollectionView interface. See [this post](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/) for more information.

To enable sort when clicking the column header, you can set to true the CanUserSortColumns of the DataGrid control.